# MySQL won't let me run scripts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with MySQL. When I try to run the script, I get one of two errors:

Preparing... [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

The first one I get if I don't select default schema. That makes some sense, but I get a different one when I do select default schema:

sequence item 6: expected str instance, bytes found

If I try to open script to run it, I get this window:

[image: Encoding options window]

I checked on different machine and the encoding was utf8, but on my machine I can only open it with latin1 encoding and that way data in database gets corrupted.

This is what I get if I choose utf8 or any other encoding:
The file contents could not be converted from 'utf8' to UTF-8: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input

This happens with any script I try, no matter the content in it.

Here is an example of a script that doesn't work:

```sql
SET @organizationId = 34299;

SET @userId = (SELECT max(user.id) FROM user);

INSERT IGNORE INTO user (id, uuid, username, password, first_name, last_name, email, owner_organization_id, sign_app_port) VALUES (@userId + 1, uuid(),'test@gmail.rs','$2a$10$Gt/hIHyrP2NNzDoC5bbu5K9CKlyZJXEy', 'Test', 'Test','test@gmail.rs', @organizationId, 8086);
INSERT IGNORE INTO user (id, uuid, username, password, first_name, last_name, email, owner_organization_id, sign_app_port) VALUES (@userId + 2, uuid(),'test2@gmail.rs','$2a$10$dva/lg08AtbWfDoC5bbuzmhfB0F.9hMi', 'Test', 'Test','test2@gmail.rs', @organizationId, 8086);
```

I couldn't find similar problems on the internet nor anything helpful. I tried installing mysql again, even tried some older versions, but that didn't work either (OS is Windows 10 professional).
Thank you in advance for anything helpful.

Comment: Please put all information (including error messages) as text in the question. Don't use screenshots.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to understand this way. Here you go:
First error:
Preparing...
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptho2i931.cnf'
Second error:
sequence item 6: expected str instance, bytes found
Third error:
The file contents could not be converted from 'utf8' to UTF-8: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input

Comment: Stackoverflow does provide an [edit] button below your question. They have a special (and good) reason for doing that.   Also without knowing the contents of those script it's impossible to give a helpful answer.   Now we have a bunch of useless pictures, without knowing what cause it because you  did not provide what you script you tried.

Comment: There you go, I hope it's a bit more clear now

Comment: when the file `hr_test_20221222.sql` is not too big, open it in Notepad, press CTRL+A (to select everythin), then CTRL+C (to copy the text), Then use [edit] on stackoverflow, and paste (using CTRL+V)  the contents of that script.   P.S. Only do this when you have readable text, if text is not readable then this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I added and example of a script that doesn't work, but as I said, it won't let me run any script, doesn't matter the content of it

Comment: Can you open that script with Notepad again, Choose `SAVE AS`, and look at the [bottom right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqNEf.png), Choose 'UTF-8' and save the file, Then please retry.   If that does not help I am out of options (and time )

Comment: Thank you Luuk for your time, but unfortunately, this didn't help me

Comment: You are using cmd?  Run this command:  `chcp 65001` to put `cmd` into utf-8 mode.  Do something to configure `notepad`.

Comment: What product is creating the error message?

Comment: @RickJames: tag `mysql-workbench` ...

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have two problems. One with the "run script" function returning a "expected str instance, not bytes", which is a long standing bug in MySQL Workbench. This bug has been open since [2021](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103026), and the resoluition is to downgrade to MySQL workbench 8.0.22.

The second issue with the Open script function may be an issue with the character encoding of the file, as suggested by @Luuk. Opening it and resaving it with a text editor is a sensible option.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, both are very helpful. My coworker gave me installation for an old version of mysql workbench and now it works fine.

Comment: Good to hear. I can't believe this is still an unresolved bug....